# My database doesn't insert immediately

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, simpletest

I am a trying to apply Test Driven Development to producing a web page and am having trouble using my database. I am developing using Cake 1.1, PHP5 and SimpleTest to unit test.

My problem is that I have a test that:

1. Inserts a row using a direct SQL statement
2. Tests if that row was inserted (by using a function in my main program.)
3. Deletes the row that was inserted.

Both steps 1 and 3 work fine but step 2 fails.

It's important to realize that if I run the test without deleting the row (I commented that out) and then ran the test again but first eliminating step 1 (once again simply commenting that line) and the test passed without a problem.

I also tried running the SQL statements directly (one after another in the editor) in PHPMyAdmin and they work perfectly.

Comment: Can we see some code to figure out if it's happening in one or multiple transactions?

Comment: I actually added the commits and it still didn't work. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 3):

Are all steps executed in the same transaction?

When not, step 2 isn't able to see the result of step 1 until step 1 commits.

Comment: They are actually separated SQL statements... I don't think they are the same transaction although they are inside the same PHP function.

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like your insert is happening inside a transaction that has not yet been committed when you attempt the test.

Can you give some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are committing the transaction in step 1?